# how to quit/close Anaconda Navigator

Tags: python, anaconda

When I tried to launch Anaconda Navigator, the screen shows that I have Anaconda Navigator opened. But I couldn't find it on my task bar. The exact language is: There is an instance of Anaconda Navigator already running. I'm using Windows 10.

How can I force Anaconda Navigator to quit and relaunch it. Thank you so much.

Comment: Try looking at the task manager ([Ctrl]+[Alt]+[Del]) and close anything anaconda related.

Comment: Thanks for response. I looked at the task manager but didn't find anything Anaconda related shown in the task manager. I don't know what to do so decided to take it here.

Answer (score 12):

The best way is to use the Task manager. There are three ways in which the Anaconda navigator may appear in the task manager.

The first is simply as "Anaconda navigator", while the second and third are as "Python" in either the Apps section or more detailed Background processes section. I have included some images below to illustrate each possibility.

*Note: to access the task manager, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> at the same time, then choose Task manager on the following menu. To close an application/process using Task manager, right click on the application/process and click "end task". Alternatively, select it with a left click and click "end task" at the bottom right of the task manager window.*

Images below:

1. **Apps: "Anaconda navigator"**

[image]

2. **Apps: Python**

[image]

3. **Background processes: Python**

[image]